# Meaning of white/black wire?

Tags: wiring

https://www.thespruce.com/electrical-wire-color-coding-1152863

This article says that white wire with black tape on it is considered to be "hot" wire.

Does this mean something different than other colors used to represent hot wire?

Comment: What it means is literally what it says... Somebody (for whatever reason) used white wire to carry the 'hot'.  To clue you (the future serviceman) that this white wire is indeed hot, it is marked with black tape.   That said, never assume ANYTHING.  Use your voltmeter and your brain to fully understand the wiring before messing with anything.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing this, 99% of the time the white with a black/red stripe will be in conjunction with a switched hot. Either

1. Two-line cable, where the white is your incoming hot and your black is your switched hot (modern NEC prefers you to use /3 in this case so you get a neutral into the switch box)
2. Multi-way switches with /3 wire, where the white wire is a traveler

Now, it's entirely possible you have no markings on your white wire, but it's still being used as outlined above. In all contexts, it's important to follow the wires to see how they are actually being used.

Answer (score 0):

### All hot colors are allowed for all hots.

Code specifies this:

- Neutrals are white or gray
- Grounds are green, yellow w/green stripe, or bare.
- Hot is *anything else*.
- In 3-phase "wild leg delta" services, one hot must be orange, but you'll never run into that.

That is the sum total of all color coding rules in NEC.

The color coding rules disappear for wires 4 AWG or larger, because those large wires are only offered in black.

### There are many kinds of hot.

Neutral wires are generally not switched nor fused, and only serve as current return to the panel.  They must be exclusive to their one circuit - neutrals cannot be "borrowed" to serve other circuits.

Hot wires, however, do lots of things.

- Always-hot: this is hot at all times.  It supplies receptacles and switches for instance.  *preferential color: Black*
- Switched-hot: This is hot when a switch or control has turned it on. These are used for controlling lights. *preferential color: red, alternate blue*
- Travelers: These are used in "3-way" circuits. One traveler is hot and the other is not, and any switch in the circuit exchanges them. One goes onward to the light, so that changing any switch flips the light. *I myself prefer yellow for these, alternate blue*.

### White wires *in cables* can be re-marked

However usually the actual re-marking is "forgotten" so you have to learn to spot it in-context.  In cables, if the cable needs a neutral wire, the white must be used for it.

If neutral is not needed (or in /2/2 cable you have a second neutral), then the white wire can be used for a hot, if it is re-marked as such.  However:

- If always-hot is present in the cable, it must be used for that.
- It can never be used for switched-hot (i.e. switch leg to lamp).

As a practical matter, in a 3-way circuit, white can be *anything* *anytime*.  Except it's not supposed to be switched-hot.

Answer (score 0):

You have linked to a site describing north American color codes, but like so many sites on the internet it doesn't say what country it is talking about. If you are not in north America please take a step back and be very careful that any information about electrical wiring you read is relevant to your country. Electrical wiring practices vary massively around the world.

I say this because I get the impression that diy.stackexchange.com is very north-america centric while electronics.stackexchange.com where this question was originally posted is less so.

---

Getting back to your question, regulations or codes are always a compromise between safety and practicality. Cables generally come with one core color coded as neutral (white in north America) but there are some applications where none of the cores are neutral.

- Light switch drops and multiway switching circuits with no neutral to the switch (IIRC the current US NEC requires neutrals to be taken to switch boxes, but there are still a lot of older installations out there).
- Circuits used to feed appliances that use two (or more) hot conductors from different legs/phases and do not require a neutral.

Rather than requiring the supply chain to stock cables of the same construction with multiple different color combinations, regulations may allow re-marking of conductors. Exactly what re-marking is an isn't allowed will again vary by country. IIRC in the US and canada re-marking on small conductor sizes is only allowed for cables, not individual wires in conduit and in the case of switch drops it must be the permanent hot wire that is re-marked and not the switched hot.

It's also critical to remember that not everyone actually follows regulations/codes, when you go into an installation which was installed by someone you don't know and trust, you *MUST* go into it with the assumption that there may be violations. It is *very* common to find wires that should have been re-marked but were not.