# Wiring a new ceiling light fixture with one white wire marked with black tape

Tags: wiring, ceiling

HELP. Which wires go to what. Note the one white marked with black tape. Thanks[image]

Comment: This may help: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/231508/25178

Comment: White wire with black marking is switch hot from switch.  It goes to black wire of light and white to white.

Comment: That's not the correct way to wire a switch loop. The marked white is supposed to be the unswitched hot. Question being did someone wire the switch loop wrong, or did someone else decide to twist the black wires together after "disconnecting everything?"

Comment: The black wires were already twisted.. so do i cap those off and do white/black to black light fixture and the white to white on fixture?  What would the black ones be for?

Comment: Black is hot, one coming from panel and one going to switch.  Cap them always.  As @Ecnerwal  says, the proper way is to have the white with black tape connected to black from panel, and the black from switch to light black, but if you do not know which black is from panel, would leave for now.

Comment: Just to be clear, when Ecnerwal said "the correct way" he meant code compliant. NEC 200.7(C)(1) specifically says the marked conductor "...shall be used only for the supply to the switch, but not as a return conductor from the switch...". To fix it the black that is part of the same cable as the marked white needs to go to the black from the light. The marked white goes to the other black, the remaining white goes to the light.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure you confirm it's what you think it is by *measuring*, either with a simple voltage tester or a multimeter. I know from experience that getting it wrong is unpleasant to say the least.

Comment: Update! Multimeter shows black wires are hot and both white are neutral. Now what??

Comment: I would like to note i have an electrictiancoming to do the big (8 light) fixture above center island. I did the single above sink myself and several other regular ceiling lights in the past. This one however is throwing me for a loop!

Comment: Also i can see where a set of black/white and another set of black/white come out together into the housing box

Answer (score 4):

The two black wires that are already twisted together carry the hot to the switch. The white wire marked with black tape is the hot coming back from the switch. The plain white wire is the neutral.

Leave the two black wires twisted together (and put a wire nut back on them!), hook the white wire with tape up to the hot terminal of the light, and the unmarked white wire up to the neutral terminal.

As Ecnerwal noted, usually the marked white wire is swapped with the black wire going to the switch, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

However, there's no serious harm in swapping the two, except for confusing future electricians.

Comment: Or you could note which cable those two wires are coming from, and swap them to be correct.